# std::vector::reserve allows random access before push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I recently learned about `std::vector::reserve` online. The websites say that reserving memory inside a `std::vector` does NOT change the size of the vector, but instead increases the `std::vector`'s capacity. After reserving, attempting to access random elements should crash.

However, when I run this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector <int> v;
    v.reserve(1000000);
    
    v[4] = 5;
    cout << v[4] << endl; // this line and the above line should cause errors

    return 0;
}
```

Nothing happens. The program runs and prints `5` to the screen, and I don't get any errors at all.

I'm not sure if I'm making a mistake here, so can somebody tell me why the above program runs?

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything might happen; it doesn't guarantee to crash.

Comment: `v[4] = 5;` This causes an out-of-bounds access, and everything after that is UB. Try `v.at(4) = 5;` instead and you'll get the error you expect.

Comment: How would it crash? The memory is allocated, memory doesn't know about the whole size vs capacity thing

Comment: You'll see that terminalogy used **a lot** with STL functions and lower level c api calls, which is why reading the docs closely is very important in these languages

Comment: @harold, The standard library implementation could tell the compiler to assume the index is less than the size. With that assumption, the compiler optimizes this code and the code around it in such a way that causes a crash. For example, `std::string str(input); if (something) { v.reserve(1000000); v[4] = 5; str += "foo"; } cout <<  str[10];`. When the compiler is aware that `v[4]` causes UB, it can realize that the if statement can never happen and `str` will retain its initial (possibly less-than-11-element) value. Then regular out-of-bounds indexing can occur, a common crash cause.

Comment: (Now of course the compiler is free to discover on its own that `v[4]` causes UB, but it's not always so easy to see through all the necessary scaffolding. An explicit contract provided by the library code would make it more straightforward. Also of course, the UB means anything the compiler produces is a valid result, including a crash out of nowhere, but I find that less compelling when taking into account how compilers actually produce output.)

Comment: I guess the other, more obvious answer is that you turn on debug mode and there's an assertion there that aborts the program. Or you use a sanitizer that checks for this and it crashes the program with an informative diagnostic.

Answer (score 2):

> After reserving, attempting to access random elements should crash.

No, it would be more correct to say that "after reserving, attempting to access random elements will result in undefined behaviour"<sup>(a)</sup>.

And undefined behaviour means *exactly* that, undefined. It may work, it may not. It may *seem* to work but set up conditions for spectacular failure later on in your program. It may not work in another implementation, it may even not work in the *same* implementation on certain days of the week.

Bottom line, don't do it.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Table 69 in ISO C++20 has the two element access operations stating exactly the same thing:

> `a[n]` - returns reference, or `const` reference for constant `a`. Semantics: `*(a.begin() + n)`.
> `a.at(n)` - returns reference, or `const` reference for constant `a`. Semantics: `*(a.begin() + n)`.

But the note immediately after that clarifies the difference:

> The member function `at()` provides bounds-checked access to container elements. `at()` throws `out_of_range` if `n >= a.size()`.

Hence, if you *need* it to "crash" (quoted since it' really raising an exception rather than crashing), use the latter.